# NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile:) does not return icon image

Tags: swift, macos, icons, nsworkspace

I am working on a MacOS application where the app should show the application icons. For some app it works, for some apps it don't.

One the app for which I do not get the application icon image is the Notes.app.

```
let icon = NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile: "/Applications/Notes.app")
```

For Numbers.app, for example, it is loading the app icon as expected.

What is the reason behind?

I have figured out that icons are only appearing for those applications where the application has an associated filetype. Applications which do not have associations does not return the icon.

There must be a was to open an .icns file. The path to it is clearly accessible and the content of the icon file should be too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I have figured out that some Applications are located under /System/Applications, but appears under /Applications too. This is causing the problem above.